# Please tell my why the answer is not $R/2$

Tags: geometric-optics

[image: figure given below]

A ray parallel to principal axis is incident at 30° from normal on concave mirror having radius of curvature R. The point on principal axis where rays are crossing the axis is Q such that PQ is R(1-1/√3) which is not the nominal focus $R/2$. Why is that?

Comment: do you know why the parallel rays should pass through focus and how is it derived mathematically ?

Comment: Related/Duplicate? [Inconsistency in ray diagram](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/550872/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [paraxial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraxial_approximation) clearly doesn't hold ($30^\circ$ is a large angle), and so neither does the usual spherical mirror equation, because of [spherical aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_aberration). Forget that equation and focal length for a moment, take the mirror to be an exact circle and treat this as a geometry problem. You will need the law of reflection: $\angle QMC = 30^\circ$.